# Spark: load file being written

Tags: csv, apache-spark, atomic

In a Spark batch I load a CSV file, in a usual way:

```
val offerDf = spark.read
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("delimiter", ";")
  .csv("myfile.csv")
```

In another linux batch (that is not in my business), the file may be writen - at the same time as I read it as both are periodic tasks.

So is there a way to be sure that the CSV file won't be modified when I read it (except scheduling the tasks, as their duration is not known)?

Comment: Modify upstream process to write to a temporary directory, and atomically move file to the final destination, once the write is ready.

Comment: OK thx. Still another problem: what if I start reading the CSV, at the same time a new version is moved? What will Spark do? Will the file be locked?